# if $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0$ then $\rho\ge-1/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This may be trivial but I am not able to prove that if $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\rho\ge-1/2$. Can anybody help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: Yes I think you are right! Thanks

Comment: I am sure that this problem has already been on this site, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also true that $$ \rho \leq 1  $$

In the case that $\rho > 1,$ take $a=1, \; b = -1, \; c = 0.$ The polynomial becomes $2 - 2 \rho = 2(1 - \rho) < 0.$

In a similar style, we can do the original problem this way: if $\rho < -\frac{1}{2},$ take $a=1, \; b = 1, \; c = 1.$ The polynomial becomes $3 + 6 \rho < 3 - 3 = 0.$

Put still another way, the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & 1 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
are $$ 1-\rho, \; 1-\rho,  \; 1 + 2 \rho $$
The quadratic form in the question is simply
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & 1 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b \\
c \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can show that the inequality is true for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq \rho \leq 1$.  Indeed, setting $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be $1$ gives
$$3+6\rho\geq 0\,,\text{ or equivalently }\rho\geq -\frac12\,.$$
Taking $(a,b,c)$ to be $(1,0,-1)$ leads to
$$2-2\rho\geq 0\,,\text{ whence }\rho\leq 1\,.$$
We shall prove that the inequality
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho\,(bc+ca+ab)\geq 0$$
holds for all $\rho\in\left[-\dfrac12,1\right]$.  This is simply because
$$\begin{align}a^2+b^2+c^2+&2\rho\,(bc+ca+ab)\\&=\frac{1+2\rho}{3}\,(a+b+c)^2+\left(\frac{1-\rho}{3}\right)\,\left((b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2\right)\geq0\,.\end{align}$$
The inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho\,(bc+ca+ab)\geq 0$ for $\rho\in\left[-\dfrac12,1\right]$ becomes an equality if and only if

- $\rho=-\frac12$ and $a=b=c$,
- $-\frac12<\rho<1$ and $a=b=c=0$, or
- $\rho=1$ and $a+b+c=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you put $a=b=c>0$ we get $$ 1+2\rho \geq 0$$ and thus a conclusion.

Comment: What about other values of $a,b,c$?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: Does it hold that $\rho\ge-1/2$?

Comment: When challenged on a math point, you should attempt to explain your reasoning.

Comment: @quasi The question is: "if $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0$ then $\rho\ge -1/2$". If we consider $a=b=c\ne 0$ we get $\rho \ge -1/2.$ And this is a correct proof. Note that we don't need to show the converse.

Comment: @quasi $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0\implies x^2+2\rho x^2\ge 0\implies 1+2\rho \ge 0.$ This, of course, doesn't prove $\rho\ge -1/2\implies a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0.$ But it is not required.

Comment: @quasi $x=a=b=c$.

Comment: @quasi You are right. We have proved (well, greedoid to be more precise) it only for a special case. But the question is: $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0\implies 1+2\rho \ge 0$. And the special case is enough to prove it.

Comment: Yes but he proved nothing!

Comment: @quasi You need to see the diference between $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0\implies 1+2\rho \ge 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+2\rho(ab+bc+ca)\ge0\iff 1+2\rho \ge 0.$ In the second case, of course, you can't work with special cases. In the first case you can do it. And it is the best way to show it.

Comment: @quasi it seems that the question is ambiguous as currently stated. One interpretation is yours, which is that for any 4-tuple ($a,b,c,\rho$) which satisfies the above inequality, one must have $\rho\ge-1/2$. The other interpretation is that if $\rho$ is a real number for which the inequality is satisfied for every triple $(a,b,c)$ of reals, then $\rho\ge-1/2.$ This answer is indeed a correct proof of the latter.

Comment: @greedoid: I see now that the error is _mine_, not yours. I misread the problem. Your argument is valid. I apologize. So as not to detract from your answer, I'll delete all my comments.

Comment: @mfl: Thanks for trying to clear up my confusion. Sorry that it took so long for me to see the light!

Comment: @Shalop: You pinpointed the issue. There are two potential interpretations, depending on the placement of the implied universal quantifier.for $a,b,c$. I read it one way, greedoid read it the other way. The problem with the way I read it is that the claim becomes trivially untrue, hence the other interpretation must have been what was intended.

Comment: Yep if $a=b=c=0$ then rho can be anything.

Comment: @Shalop: Yes, more generally, if $ab+bc+ca\le 0$, then $\rho$ can be less than $-1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=b=1$ and $c=x> -1/2$ then we have $$-2\rho\leq {x^2+2\over 2x+1}=:f(x)$$

Since $f$ achieve minimum $1$ at $x=1$ we have $\boxed{\rho\geq-{1\over 2}}$.

And if $x<-{1\over 2}$ we get $$-2\rho\geq {x^2+2\over 2x+1}$$

Since $f$ achieve maximum $-2$ for $x=-3$ we have also $-2\rho \geq -2$ so $\boxed{\rho \leq 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

With $M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $v = (a,b,c)$ we have

$$
v^{\top}I_3 v + 2\rho v^{\top}M v \ge 0\Rightarrow v^{\top}\left(I_3+2\rho M\right)v \ge0
$$

so choosing $\rho$ such that $I_3+2\rho M \gt 0$ (definite positiveness)

with the conditions in the sub-determinants

$$
1-\rho^2 > 0\\
(\rho -1)^2 (2 \rho +1) > 0
$$

follows in $$\rho \ge -\frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Consider $(a,b,c)$ , then

1) $a^2+b^2+c^2=$

$ (a,b,c)\cdot(a,b,c)=||(a,b,c)||^2$.

2) $ab+bc +ca =$

$(a,b,c) \cdot (b,c,a) =$

$||(a,b,c)|| ||(a,b,c)|| \cos \phi =$

$||(a,b,c)||^2 \cos \phi$.

Combining:

$a^2+b^2+c^2 +2\rho (ab+bc+cd) \ge$

$0$, or

$||(a,b,c)||^2 + 2\rho ||(a,b,c)||^2 \cos \phi \ge 0.$

Assuming $(a,b,c)\not = (0,0,0)$:

$1+ 2\rho \cos \phi \ge 0$;

$\rho \cos \phi \ge -1/2$.

1) $0 \le \cos \phi \le 1$, then

$\rho \ge -1/2$.

2) $-1/2 \le \cos \phi \le 0$, then

$\rho \le 1$.

Note : $\cos \phi \ge -1/2$, since

$(a+b+c)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2) = $

$2(ab +ac+bc)$.

We have:

$-||(a,b,c)||^2 \le $

$(a+b+c)^2 -||(a,b,c)||^2 =$

$ 2||(a,b,c)||^2\cos \phi.$

Hence: $-1 \le 2\cos \phi $.